# ListView app frustratingly slow, unable to figure out why

Tags: android, listview

Everything seems to be okay (other than being quite laggy) except the fact that I am unable to see the last few views of my ListView app. I tried to change the height of my custom view layout for each ListView item and I realized that the smaller the height, the more views I could not see. This meant that there was a fixed length of height at the bottom of my ListView that I am unable to scroll to and I have no idea why.

Code from MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] titles;
    String[] descriptions;
    int[] drawables = {R.drawable.number0, R.drawable.number2, R.drawable.number3, R.drawable.number4, R.drawable.number5, R.drawable.number6, R.drawable.number7, R.drawable.number8, R.drawable.number9, R.drawable.number10};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.title);
        descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);

        ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myadapter myadapter = new myadapter(this, titles, drawables, descriptions);
        l.setAdapter(myadapter);

    }
}
class myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        Context c;
        int[] drawables;
        String[] titles;
        String[] descriptions;

    public myadapter(Context context, String[] titles, int[] drawables, String[] descriptions ) {
        super(context,R.layout.single_row, R.id.title,titles);
        c=context;
        this.drawables = drawables;
        this.titles = titles;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }

    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = i.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        }
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);

        image.setImageResource(drawables[position]);
        title.setText(titles[position]);
        description.setText(descriptions[position]);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Code from custom layout xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/number0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity_main.xml file simply contains a listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the video tutorial uses a png file format, he might have used smaller files instead. Your list view might be slow because it takes time to draw so many resources to display it? Did u try just displaying the text only?

sorry this is more like a comment than a answer, but I can't post comments till I've reached 50 reps

Comment: Good advice. I tried to remove the image component and now my app is very smooth! I did not think that drawing of the png file would take up so much resources. Thanks for you help! :) Do you know the reason to the other problem I am facing? I am somehow unable to scroll to the very bottom of my ListView.

Comment: Can you include more details of how u cannot scroll to the bottom?
Is the ListView set to match parent for both layout width and height?

Comment: My ListView has 10 items. When I scroll down , I can only see half of the 9th item and none of the 10th item. I keep scrolling but it just stops there ( as if it has hit the bottom already). I tried changing the height of each view item in my listview and the smaller the height, the more items that are not shown. This meant that there seems to be a fixed space at the bottom of my ListView that is not shown. Could it be that the system wrongly perceive my phone screen to be longer than it actually is? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: when u scroll, can u see all the list that is displayed ? i.e. is anything blocking any of your list when u first launch the app?

Comment: Nope nothing is blocking it. I can see everything until except the last few items in my list. lol so strange.

Comment: I have faced this problem before with my app, it turns out that something is blocking my list view. Maybe something is blocking your listview? can u attach a screenshot of what is being blocked by the 'white box' ?

Comment: And please accept my answer if u think it solves your problem tks.

Comment: omg I understand what is wrong already. I did not set my listview in xml height and width as match_parent, thats why the formatting seems to be off. Thank you for your time!! XDD

Comment: sorry I was busy just now